# Require fix for Tuckey URLRewrite filter rules

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to understand tuckey urlRewrite to write a `rule` but am unable to do it.

I have a `Servlet` that has URL Pattern defined `@WebServlet("/user/*")`. At the load of `Servlet` I get URL like `http://localhost:8080/Navigation/user/*`.

How can I make a rule so whenever `/user/` URL is loaded it should go to `http://localhost:8080/Navigation/user/list`. I tried this:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/user/*$</from>
    <to>/user/list</to>
</rule>
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<urlrewrite use-context="true">
    <rule>
        <from>(.*)/user/(.*)$</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect">$1/user/list</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Where `$1` represents anything that is before `/user/` i.e. denoted by the first `(.*)`.

A read through this [manual](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#tips) might also help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. When I use you rule than get "http://localhost:8080/user/list" URL. I am losing my Context (Navigation) from url. I tried %{context-path}/ but no success. Any help

Comment: Nope no success still same result :(

Comment: @Rashid Please check if you are deploying it properly and also I hope you are configuring everything else properly. Ok do one thing, include Navigation also in `<to type="permanent-redirect">$1/Navigation/user/list</to>` and then check if it works. Which server are you using and how are you configuring the xml?

Comment: Onething I have noticed with type="permanent-redirect" if use-context="true" is not added than I always get URL without context. Does permanent-redirect add something to project,browser, eclipse etc and I am unable to reset it even if I completely remove URLRewriting from my project. Do you have any idea of that? . When you reply this I accept your answer as this is my side problem. I am using Eclipse with JBoss 7.1.1

Comment: @Rashid the manual link I had given in the answer has all that you need, still can go through this: http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#to, this explains the difference between `redirect`, `permanent-redirect` and `temporary-redirect`. You can also try using `redirect` instead of `permanent-redirect`. By the way `use-context` is by default `false` so the context would be removed if you do not set this attribute.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I accept your answer and will explore more in this.

Answer (score 0):

try giving like this `<to type="redirect">`

Comment: if I add redirect than Navigation is stripped out from URL and becomes "http://localhost:8080/user/list. How to solve this?